# Handle one HTTP request in multiple cores

Tags: java, php, c++, node.js

I'm struggling with flowing CPU cores issue.

I have in my application some hard charts data collection logic which is based on many related to each other data, it is currently build on PHP

**So issue is** basically my machine has **multiple CPU cores** but one **http request take only one CPU core** in any php mode Fast CGI , CGI  ...

So i was wondering is there some workaround for this in any of following languages

**PHP , NODEJS , JAVA , C++ ??**

So that your **one execution** will use/involve multiple CPU cores

Comment: None of the languages you mention will automatically use multiple threads for an operation that you coded in sequential, single threaded code.  Instead, you would need to select an environment with threads and then write your code in a mutli-threaded fashion to use multiple threads and to engage multiple cores.

Comment: Aha ok thanks, so basically only way to go to split it among multiple threads and get result in parent thread right ?

Comment: That is the general way it would work.  We can really only discuss in more specifics if you showed the actual implementation code.

Comment: aha i see, for now it's enough for me, i will see if i stuck during separation of code i will post it here, Thank again for help

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use multithreading for that. For example in PHP you will need to install pthreads from PECL:

```
> /<php-install-dir>/bin/pecl install pthreads
```

then enable it by adding the .so extension in the php.ini.

Then you can run threads like this:

```
<?php
    class MyThread extends Thread {
        public function run() {
            /* Your code here */
        }
    }
    $thread1 = new MyThread();
    $thread2 = new MyThread();
    $thread1->start();
    $thread2->start();
?>
```

It is very similar in all programming languages.

Comment: But will 1 thread use multiple cores ? is it at least possible?

Comment: No, it one thread will run on one core. You need to split your work between many threads.

Answer (score 2):

Basically a **single** incoming request will be managed by a single thread on most web frameworks

**Multi thread support in most web frameworks**

Most framework will leverage the many cores of the machine by dealing with several requests at the same time. If you deal with 100 requests concurrently from 100 users, each one will use a thread... And if you have 4 cores, roughly each core will manage 25 threads efficiantly using your hardware capabilities.

It is so unecessary in most case to make a single request be handled by several threads.

**If you request is slow and has high CPU usage**

You can of course use multiple threads to deal with a single request but you have to be sure it is worth it. Usually making an algorithm multi thread comes with an overhead meaning that the global throughput of your web server will decrease.

This is a tradeof between making one slow request that is heavy on CPU usage faster and overall throughput.

A web framework level there absolutely no gain to do that in multithread as basically the framework is only concerned with receiving and sending stream of a data, a very slow operation compared to a given CPU speed.

And if your actual algorithm do benefit from parallelism, well then it is your responsability as developper to implement that multi thread version of the algorithm.

This make you program much more complex, much harder to reason is likely not worth it if your request isn't quite slow already like a few seconds or more and that delay come mostly from computations rather than waiting for the DB or other web services.

So before starting on something overly complex, be sure you actually need it.

**Modern web framework take the opposite approach**

Actually in opposition the trend is the opposite. Most http requests are just waiting for external resources, be it a response from the DB, the response of another service or sending the response to the network interface.

So modern framework like Node.js in javascript or Vertex in java take the opposite approach.

A given thread will not wait for a given request to finish. Each time the program is waiting for an external ressource (DB, external service...) the thread is freed and deal with the other operations like managing other requests. Later on when the response is available the request processing is resumed.

This prove to increase the overall throughput of webservers, at least for all the cases where there no much CPU usage per requested but most of the time is spent waiting.

Comment: Ok thanks for this short explanation